# Question about sudo fdisk -1

Tags: 14.04, sudo, fdisk

I've been trying to mount an external HDD to my ubuntu server (14.04) but when I try to use the sudo fdisk -1 function it tells me that its an invalid option, is there any way I can fix this?
Or any other way i can go about to mount the external HDD and share is using Samba?

Cheers,
Jarryd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are trying to run is:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

That last character is a lowercase **L**, not the number **1**. A lot of commands in Linux take options that are usually specified by a hyphen and then a character, for example `-l`, `-i`, or `-h`. That character is usually a letter.

Sometimes, an option could also include a number, but it usually comes after a letter as well, for example:

`du -d1 /path/to/folder`

The command is `du` and the option being passed is `-d1`, that's a `d` followed by the number `1`.

Comment: Cheers! I feel dumb now XD

Comment: No worries @Jarryd, we learn from mistakes. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Don't forget to [mark an answer as your accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate to everyone that your question has been solved. You do that by clicking the check mark to the left of an answer!